# Annotate last use of variables in (c) source code with (g)awk

Tags: c, bash, awk, tac

I have a file with c Sourcecode such as

```
func2(&x5, &x6, x4, (arg1[3]));
func2(&x7, &x8, x4, (arg1[2]));  
func(&x13, &x14, 0x0, x12, x9);     
func(&x17, &x18, x16, x8, x5);
uint64_t x19 = (x18 + x6); 
func2(&x20, &x21, x11, 0xff);
func2(&x24, &x25, x11, 0xff11));
func(&x26, &x27, 0x0, x25, x22);
uint64_t x28 = (x27 + x23);
func(&x29, &x30, 0x0, x11, x24);
func(&x31, &x32, x30, x13, x26);
func(&x33, &x34, x32, x15, x28);
```

And I would like to annotate the last usage of a variable. Such as:

```
func2(&x5, &x6, x4, (arg1[3]));
func2(&x7, &x8, x4, (arg1[2]));   // 4,7
func(&x17, &x18, x16, x8, x5);    // 5,8,16,17
uint64_t x19 = (x18 + x6);        // 6,19
func2(&x20, &x21, x11, 0xff);     // 21,20
func2(&x24, &x25, x11, 0xff11));   
func(&x26, &x27, 0x0, x25, x22);  // 25,22
uint64_t x28 = (x27 + x23);       // 23,27,28
func(&x29, &x30, 0x0, x11, x24);  // 24,11,29
func(&x31, &x32, x30, x13, x26);  // 26,13,30,31
```

The comments list all the variables, which are not used below. (Semantic behind that: those could be reused/freed afterwards.)

The variables follow the regex `/x([0-9]){1,3}/`.
I tried to feed that file via `tac` into `gawk` with the following cmd: 
`tac file.c |  gawk ' match($0,/x([0-9]){1,3}/,a) && ! seen[a[0]] {printf "%s// %s\n",$0,a[0];seen[a[0]]=1;}{print}' |tac`
which produces

```
func2(&x5, &x6, x4, (arg1[3]));
func2(&x5, &x6, x4, (arg1[3]));// x5
func2(&x7, &x8, x4, (arg1[2]));  
func2(&x7, &x8, x4, (arg1[2]));  // x7
func(&x13, &x14, 0x0, x12, x9);     
func(&x13, &x14, 0x0, x12, x9);     // x13
func(&x17, &x18, x16, x8, x5);
func(&x17, &x18, x16, x8, x5);// x17
uint64_t x19 = (x18 + x6); 
uint64_t x19 = (x18 + x6); // x19
func2(&x20, &x21, x11, 0xff);
func2(&x20, &x21, x11, 0xff);// x20
func2(&x24, &x25, x11, 0xff11));
func2(&x24, &x25, x11, 0xff11));// x24
func(&x26, &x27, 0x0, x25, x22);
func(&x26, &x27, 0x0, x25, x22);// x26
uint64_t x28 = (x27 + x23);
uint64_t x28 = (x27 + x23);// x28
func(&x29, &x30, 0x0, x11, x24);
func(&x29, &x30, 0x0, x11, x24);// x29
func(&x31, &x32, x30, x13, x26);
func(&x31, &x32, x30, x13, x26);// x31
func(&x33, &x34, x32, x15, x28);
func(&x33, &x34, x32, x15, x28);// x33
```

I am quite close already, but obviously this is not what I want.

- How can I globalize the match of `match` such that it recognizes all occurrences in the function call?
- Avoid printing the line twice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big issue is that `match()` only finds the *first* match of a regular expression. You have to loop through each line repeatedly to find all the variables in it.

If you read the file once to find uses of variables, and then read it again to print out the last-used entries based on the first passes data collection, it's possible to do it in just gawk. This shell script wraps it for convenience so you don't have to manually specify the source file twice:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
gawk '
NR == FNR {
    s = $0
    while (match(s, /\<x([0-9]+)\>/, a)) {
        seen[a[1]] = FNR
        s = substr(s, RSTART + RLENGTH)
    }
    next
}
{
    s = $0
    lasts = ""
    while (match(s, /\<x([0-9]+)\>/, a)) {
        if (seen[a[1]] == FNR) {
            if (lasts == "")
                lasts = a[1]
            else
                lasts = lasts "," a[1]
        }
        s = substr(s, RSTART + RLENGTH)
    }
    if (lasts == "")
        print $0
    else
        printf "%s\t// %s\n", $0, lasts;
}
' "$1" "$1"
```

Example usage:

```
$ ./lastvars foo.c
func2(&x5, &x6, x4, (arg1[3]));
func2(&x7, &x8, x4, (arg1[2]));     // 7,4
func(&x13, &x14, 0x0, x12, x9);         // 14,12,9
func(&x17, &x18, x16, x8, x5);  // 17,16,8,5
uint64_t x19 = (x18 + x6);  // 19,18,6
func2(&x20, &x21, x11, 0xff);   // 20,21
func2(&x24, &x25, x11, 0xff11));
func(&x26, &x27, 0x0, x25, x22);    // 25,22
uint64_t x28 = (x27 + x23); // 27,23
func(&x29, &x30, 0x0, x11, x24);    // 29,11,24
func(&x31, &x32, x30, x13, x26);    // 31,30,13,26
func(&x33, &x34, x32, x15, x28);    // 33,34,32,15,28
```

Comment: Works perfectly. One must be sure to not execute `./lastvars foo.c > foo.c`, which will erase the contents of `foo.c`. Instead, output into a different file and copy to another.